# Bootstrap Responsive on Resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Twitter Bootstrap layout with 3 columns. The middle colomn cannot be toggled but the left and right columns can be hidden and shown. How would it be possible for me to make it so when the left column is hidden the middle one spans all the way across and so on.

So if I have a *3 6 3* grid and I hide the left column it becomes a *6 3* grid. How could I, using jquery, make it so it automatically changes the span to *9 3* so it fills the page?

I have tried changing the attributes with jquery but I couldn't get that to work, I'm not too knowledgeable in jquery.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="http://bootswatch.com/amelia/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://bootswatch.com/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
      .sidebar-nav {
        padding: 9px 0;
      }

      @media (max-width: 980px) {
        /* Enable use of floated navbar text */
        .navbar-text.pull-right {
          float: none;
          padding-left: 5px;
          padding-right: 5px;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <link href="http://bootswatch.com/default/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
              Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
            </p>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a id="lefttoggle">Left</a></li>
              <li><a id="righttoggle">Right</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="left" class="span3">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.well -->
        </div><!--/span-->


        <div id="middle" class="span6">
          <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="span4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="span4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
          </div><!--/row-->
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="span4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
            <div class="span4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/span-->
          </div><!--/row-->
        </div><!--/span-->
         <div id="right" class="span3">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.well -->
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->


      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
      </footer>

    </div><!--/.fluid-container-->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lefttoggle").click(function(){
    $("#left").toggle(1000);
  });
   $("#righttoggle").click(function(){
    $("#right").toggle(1000);
});
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is a live view of what it looks like:

http://onlinement.iheff.net/new.php

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Small note: it would look better if you only animate the width of the sidebars rather than the width and the height.  Also don't forget that you'll need to change the middle section to `span12` if both the left and right are hidden.

Comment: @snumpy good call, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't animated, but should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lefttoggle").click(function(){
        $("#left").toggle(1000);

        if($('#middle').hasClass('span6')){
            $('#middle').removeClass('span6').addClass('span9');
        }
        else{
            $('#middle').removeClass('span9').addClass('span6');
        }
    });

    $("#righttoggle").click(function(){
        $("#right").toggle(1000);
        if($('#middle').hasClass('span6')){
            $('#middle').removeClass('span6').addClass('span9');
        }
        else{
            $('#middle').removeClass('span9').addClass('span6');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I never knew jquery could have "if" statements, neat! I did run into a small problem, though. When I hide the left side it resizes the middle to span9 just fine, but it pushes the right sidebar to the bottom. It works fine if I use span8 but I'm just being nit picky haha

Comment: @iHeff jQuery is a **JavaScript** library, so you can write anything you want that is valid code in JavaScript. `$()` simply provides a normalized way to select DOM elements, and methods like `click()` are just normalized event handlers. The whole point is to allow you to avoid spending time dealing with browser inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you're looking for.

To switch to 9 + 3:

```
$('#left').removeClass('span3').addClass('hidden');
$('#middle').removeClass('span6').addClass('span9');
```

To switch back:

```
$('#right').removeClass('span9').addClass('span6');
$('#left').removeClass('hidden').addClass('span3');
```

Comment: Thank you! Gonna have to go with Tieson's though because of the conditional statements